# The question excerpts take too much vertical space

Tags: discussion, design

The question excerpts shown e.g. on the list of newest questions look unusually large to me, it seems that fewer questions fit onto my screen than with other SE site designs.

I checked this using the Chrome Developer Tools and found that in the Skeptics design the excerpts are 175px high, while in the new beta design they are only 142px high.

Here is a comparison of the Skeptics theme and the new beta theme:

[image]

[image]

The Skeptics theme has significantly more whitespace, especially between the question text and the tags/user card, but also above and below the user card.

This means that fewer questions fit onto the screen, and also the votes/answers/views count looks a bit strange due to the large amount of whitespace below it.

I'd suggest to reduce the amount of vertical spacing in the Skeptics theme.

Comment: Also, the copy lines "I am not... Christopher" have a smaller font and less interline than the beta theme, thus those 175px actually dedicate *even less space* to important stuff in favour of white space!

Comment: It's different! Aaaaah!